# Can't copy local files to remote (Windows -> Docker Machine Oracle VM)

Tags: linux, docker, copy, virtual-machine, scp

I tried using
`scp -r C:\Users\username\Desktop\Docker node1@ip:/home/docker`, but it asks for a password. So I set up a password on my node1 machine but I get: `Permission denied, please try again.` Guest additions and shared folders from VM didn't work, so I'm trying to get this to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

can you ssh into the machine?
Make sure to use the correct password for username node1

Comment: Yes I can. I can create files with touch as well, only copying doesn't work. And thats what I did, I just recreated all the files :/

Comment: you can ssh and then touch the files in /home/docker? 
maybe permissions on folder you are trying to copy 
try chmod -R 777 C:\Users\username\Desktop\Docker